# Jetty 7 hightide distribution, JSP and JSTL support

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, jstl

I've been struggling with Jetty 7 and its support for JSP and JSTL.

My JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<head>
  <title>blah</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="data">
    <tr class="columns">
      <td>Hour</td>
      <c:forEach var="campaign" items="${campaigns}">
        <td>${campaign}</td>            
      </c:forEach>
    </tr>

    <c:forEach var="hour" items="${results}">
      <tr>
        <td class="hour">${hour.key}</td>
        <c:forEach var="campaign" items="${campaigns}">
          <td>${hour[campaign]}</td>
        </c:forEach>            
      </tr>     
     </c:forEach>
  </table>  
</body>
</html>
```

The JSP portions above work as expected. JSTL, however, does not. The campaigns and results variables are request attributes set by a servlet.

I get the following errors:

```
WARN: ... compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl: Unknown element (deferred-value) in attribute
WARN: ... compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl: Unknown element (deferred-value) in attribute
WARN: ... compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl: Unknown element (deferred-value) in attribute
ERROR: ... javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
```

- I am not bundling any jar files into my .war file deployed to jetty.
- The version of jetty I'm using is: jetty-hightide-7.0.1.v20091125

The classpath:

```
/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-xml-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-http-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-continuation-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-server-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-security-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-servlet-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-webapp-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-deploy-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-servlets-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jsp/ant-1.6.5.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jsp/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jsp/jetty-jsp-2.1-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jsp/jsp-2.1-glassfish-9.1.1.B60.25.p2.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jsp/jsp-api-2.1-glassfish-9.1.1.B60.25.p2.jar:/usr/local/jetty/resources:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-util-7.0.1.v20091125.jar:/usr/local/jetty/lib/jetty-io-7.0.1.v20091125.jar
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Lior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
> ```

This exception basically means that the mentioned method cannot be found in the runtime classpath, while it was available in the compiletime classpath of either the class or one of its dependencies.

This [method](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#getELContext%28%29) is introduced in JSP 2.1 which gets hand in hand with Servlet 2.5. Since Jetty 7 is supposed to support Servlet 2.5 and thus isn't the suspect here, the only cause can be that the `web.xml` is declared as Servlet 2.4 or lower instead of Servlet 2.5. So, to fix this particular problem, you need to declare your `web.xml` as at least Servlet 2.5. The `<web-app>` tag should look like this:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="YourWebAppID"
    version="2.5">
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, then the other cause is that the `/WEB-INF/lib` or even worse the `/JRE/lib` or `/JRE/lib/ext` is cluttered with appserver-specific libraries containing an older Servlet API version. E.g. `servlet-api.jar` from Tomcat or `j2ee.jar`  or `javaee.jar` from Glassfish, etcetera. You'll need to clean up those classpath folders from any libraries which doesn't belong there, because they get precedence in classloading and will override the appserver's own libraries. Appserver-specific libraries belongs to the appserver in question, not to the webapp or JRE.

---

That said and apart from the actual problem, the `@page` attributes `language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"` are all superfluous. The `language` already defaults to Java and the `contentType` already defaults to `text/html` and the `charset` will already be set to `UTF-8` if you set `pageEncoding="UTF-8"`. So the following is already sufficient:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: My web.xml already uses the 2.5 version as shown above. No go.

Comment: Modified my <%@page directive to match your suggestions. Thanks. Still struggling with the main issue tho.

Comment: No jar files are bundles into the .war file exported by eclipse.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see another causes. Good luck with the problem. I'd be curious to the root cause though.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'll update this question when I find a solution (hopefully).

Comment: Accepting the answer, no solution was found. Moved to GlassFish3 instead.

Answer (score 7):

With Jetty 8, the situation is a bit different, in case this helps anyone.

For JSTL 1.2, rather surprisingly, the taglib has to be:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

with JSTL 1.2 from (mavenishly):

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

I can't really explain why the URL lacks 'jsp', but it works this way.

Answer (score 4):

tsk... I don;t have privilege to comment. I am using Jetty 7.1.6 and answer provided by [bmargulies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131433/bmargulies) works.

Basically, changing URI from

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

to

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

makes taglibs to work in Jetty 7.

-Nishant

Answer (score 4):

The reason why http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core doesn't work is because the code in the Jasper Jsp parser used by Jetty (org.apache.jasper.glassfish:jar:2.2.2.xxx) assumes that that uri is a systemuri (see TldScanner.java) and it will not put any taglibs with this uri in its tablib location cache. I don't know why this assumption is in the code but it is. Seems to be a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (got JSTL working now thanks to the above discussion). I am using embedded Jetty, and for JSP I use this Maven coordinate: org.glassfish.web:jsp-impl:2.2.1. I will try using another JSP implementation.

Good find (spotting the issue in TldScanner)!

Answer (score 1):

Thx for the tip Steve! The bug seems still there, here's a workaround to run at Jetty initialisation. It did the trick for me.

```
import org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner;
import java.util.Set;

Field field = TldScanner.class.getDeclaredField("systemUris");
field.setAccessible(true);
((Set<?>)field.get(null)).clear();
field.setAccessible(false);
```

Comment: Seems like it's bug. Switching to jasper 6.0.37 helps with that problem. Exclude "all*.exclude module: 'org.apache.jasper.glassfish'" (gradle syntax) and add "compile 'org.apache.tomcat:jasper:6.0.37'".