# Setup Jetty 7 with JSP engine

Tags: jsp, jetty, javac

I've been trying to get Jetty to run my web app via a custom launcher (embedded).  I am trying to figure out how to tell Jetty which java compiler to use for JSPs.  I want to do what `java -jar start.jar -OPTIONS=jsp` does, but without using start.jar.

Here is what shows on the console:

```
Javac exception, Unable to find a javac compiler; com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK
```

Do I need to put the javac libraries into my classpath?

Comment: This post seems like he has it working, but it's not clear how he is launching his jetty environment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534883/jetty-7-hightide-distribution-jsp-and-jstl-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable pointing to the root folder of the JDK. Here's an extract of the [Sun guide on the subject](http://developers.sun.com/docs/javacaps/installing/jcapsinstgui.inst_jdk_javahome_t.html):

> 2) To set `JAVA_HOME`:
>
> 1. Right click My Computer and select Properties.
> 2. On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit `JAVA_HOME` to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02`.

Most servletcontainers like Tomcat doesn't need it because they ships with its own compiler.

Comment: actually I had this, it seems I needed to have tools.jar in my classpath.

Comment: To be sure, aren't you confusing JDK with JRE?

Comment: I'm using the JRE inside of the JDK (jdk1.6/jre/bin/java).  The java compiler (in tools.jar) is not by default on the classpath, AFAIK.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that tomcat had its own compiler; Thanks.  This probably works around licensing issues with redistributing the JDK.  The jsp engine I pulled out of eclipse used some ant javac task to compile the JSP.